# Hypergeometric test in R

Tags: r

I am trying to replicate the hypergeometric test in R ( only the pmf parameter, equal to the `dhyper`  function in R).

I made this formula:

```
choose(K,k)*choose(N-K,n-k)/choose(N,n)
```

and when I use the with these numbers I get:

```
K=8
k=20
N=10000
n=35

> choose(K,k)*choose(N-K,n-k)/choose(N,n)
[1] 0
```

which is false.The desired result is:

```
dhyper(8,35,10000,20)

> dhyper(8,35,10000,20)
[1] 1.128574e-15
```

Why do I get a wrong result? I tried even with the `lchoose` and I only get `-Inf`. Is R able to do this?

Comment: Those two values are pretty much equivalent from a numerical perspective.

Comment: I'd also add that `choose(K,k)` is in fact 0 so you probably reversed k and K. You should also look at the formula given on `?dhyper`. I think the problem is more with _you_ not being able to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In dhyper(x, m, n, k) you have:

x         the number of white balls drawn without replacement from an urn which contains both black and white balls.

m          the number of white balls in the urn.

n       the number of black balls in the urn.

k       the number of balls drawn from the urn.

So, you formula must be:

```
choose(m,k)*choose(N-m,k-x)/choose(N,k)
```

where

```
N = m + n
```

So:

```
choose(35,8)*choose(10035-35,20-8)/choose(10035,20)
```

must give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your formula.

K = number of white balls in the urn
k = number of white balls that we want to extract

In your case, k > K, so we want to extract more white balls than we have and the probability is 0.

The inputs of dhyper are different.

```
dhyper(k, K, N - K, n)
```

The result is 0, as expected.